# Run external tool on save file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, restructuredtext, texlipse

I have a Restructured Text file in my Texlipse project in Eclipse. I set up an external tool to build it to HTML with location:

```
 /bin/bash
```

and arguments:

```
-c "
/path/to/rst2html --verbose ${resource_loc} ${resource_loc}.html
echo Done. Errors: $?
"
```

How can I get Eclipse to run this external tool every time I save the ReST file?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to this is to add a Builder to the list of builders for the project. This is configured in the Project Properties in the Builders section.

You can add an 'Ant' based builder or a 'Program' which could invoke your /bin/bash directly.

Note that the builder will be called every time Eclipse thinks the project needs building, not just when you save that particular file.

Comment: Yes, I went down that route but bumped exactly into that problem -- whenever I edit my latex files it will then rebuild the rest file.  But thanks.